# Problems setting background for grouped UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to have a background image behind my `UITableView`. This works fine, but for each grouped `UITableView` it seems to be using my background image. I just want it to use the background image once:

Note: This is all inside of a `UITableViewController` class

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]autorelease];
    self.tableView.opaque = NO;
    self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'each grouped UITableView'? Different sections inside one UITableView?

Comment: yes, different sections inside one UITableView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things:

Set background view (color) not in the `UITableViewController`, but in his parent (`UINavigationController` most likely, right?)

```
self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // or whatever your image is
```

Set clear color for tableView background color (and optionally for its `separatorColor`)

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```